# Значення слова "непричком"

Tags: значення-слів

[Словник Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/32726-neprychkom.html) каже:

> **Непричком** и **непричкома**, *нар*. Точно, будто, сказать-бы. Желех. *Купив,
>   пане, коняку, а у неї під хвостом, непричкома як панська шапка.* Канев.
>   у.

Але в текстах знайдених Гуглом я знаходжу це слово майже винятково в значені *зненацька, раптово, ненароком.*

Так яке ж значення цього слова?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) знає трохи більше:

> **Непри́чком (непри́чкома)** - немов, наче, ніби, сказати б; приміром,
>   наприклад, часом, бува; випадково, ненароком.